# UnicodeDecodeError: when trying to save image to the django model

Tags: python, django, image, model

I have this model:

```
class MyModel(Model):

    other_field = CharField(max_length=200)
    image = ImageField(upload_to='images/', null=True, blank=True, )
```

I enter into the shell

```
Python manage.py shell
```

Then:

```
import os
from django.core.files import File

my_image1_path = 'C:\\Users\\Amin\\PycharmProjects\\myproject\\myimage1.png'
my_image1_file = File(open(my_image1_path ))
from myapp.models import MyModel
model_ins = MyModel.objects.get(id=1)
model_ins.image.save('myimage1.png', my_image1_file )
```

I encounter this error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x89 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

I have another ins in my model and I encounter no error with that other image file:

```
import os
from django.core.files import File

import os
from django.core.files import File

my_image1_path = 'C:\\Users\\Amin\\PycharmProjects\\myproject\\myimage2.svg'
my_image1_file = File(open(my_image2_path ))
from myapp.models import MyModel
model_ins = MyModel.objects.get(id=2)
model_ins.image.save('myimage2.svg', my_image2_file )
```

Any clue what is the problem with the image1?!

Comment: You open it as text, not as binary.

Comment: How should I open it as a binary?

Comment: Why is it good with svg and not with png?

Comment: because svg is not a binary format, if you open it, you see that it is just text, it is an "dialect" of XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `open` will open the file as text by default, not as a binary stream.

You thus can open it by setting the mode to `'rb'`:

```
with open(my_image1_path, 'rb') as f:
    my_image1_file = File(f)
```

Make use of a context manager (the `with` block), to ensure that the file is closed properly.

Comment: Should I put `model_ins.image.save('myimage2.svg', my_image2_file )` inside with or outside it?

Comment: @AminBa: I think you can put this outside it, but if not, inside is fine as well. Normally it is better to make context scopes as "short as possible".

Comment: I guess there must be a problem here. I am writing a script to read image files from a directory of images and assign each to an instance of MyModel. Some of the images are SVG, some png, some jpg, etc. Should I use the same code as you mentioned above for all of them?

Comment: @AminBa: if it is an svg, then the read mode should be `'r'`.

Comment: I did this: ```if image_name.split('.')[-1] == 'svg':
    a = 'r'
else:
    a = 'rb'
with open(image_path, a) as f:
    image_file = File(f)```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Can you advise me about this question as well:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62331129/how-to-stop-python-development-server-from-terminal